# Javascript form validation didn't work probably

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I know this is stupid but i don't know why my validation function doesn't work. It keeps blinking "Need to fill both input !!!" . Pls help me

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Login form</h2>
  <form action="signin.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <h3 id='error'></h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Enter username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button name="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
function validation(){
    var username = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var error = document.getElementById('error');
    if(username === "" || password === ""){
        error.innerHTML="Need to fill both input !!!"
        setTimeout(()=>error.remove(),3000);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keeps blinking \"Need to fill both input !!!\"". This should show it at most once, after which your validation breaks (because you remove the element, and later your `getElementById` fails).

Comment: oh sr i mean when i submit the form it shows once and still got submited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, the first time validation happens, you *remove* your `error` element. It finishes fine, but with dire consequences. The second time validation happens, `document.getElementById('error')` will give you `undefined`, causing `error.innerHTML=` to fail, which means the function does not return `false` or prevent default, so the `submit` event is free to continue unimpeded.

Instead of *removing* `error`, *empty* it (the same way you filled it is fine).

```
setTimeout(() => error.innerHTML = "", 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have misspelling in

```
getElementById('user**N**ame')
```

It should be in `lowercase` - username

Comment: But i have <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Enter username">